# activerecord not returning column information

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sql-server-2008-r2, tiny-tds

I have a very simple ruby script where columns_names is not being returned.  The code below returns the proper row count of 10,000.  However, a request for the columns names returns an empty array [].  My gemfile.lock shows I'm using activerecord (4.1.2.rc2).

This is so simple, yet I am unable to determine my problem.

```
require 'active_record'  # v4.1.4
require 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'  # v4.1.0
require 'pp'

ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names = false
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    adapter: 'sqlserver',
    host: '--------',
    database: '----',
    timeout: 35
)

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'table_name'
end

pp Model.count
pp Model.column_names
pp Model.attribute_names
```

=*= Updates =*=

SqlServer is 10.5 (2008 R2).  I updated active_record etal to 4.1.4.  No change.  Model.attribute_names returns an empty array.  The properties will return ok when I switch to sqlite3 adapter and provide a dummy db file.

**=*= Almost Success =*=**

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'dbo.Model'
end
```

Ok.  I don't understand the database details.  But forcing in 'dbo.' to the front of the table name returned the column names.  It was just something I decided to try on a whim.

The bad news is that the find_by_sql quoted in the comments returns an empty array [].  It does not return and array of empty Nil instances of # as it does without the dbo.

Where should I report this behavior to?  Thanks.

Logger output:

```
pp Model.column_names
pp Model.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = #{Model.table_name}")
```

yields:

```
D, [2014-08-01T16:17:54.299270 #4072] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36mSQL (1.0ms)[0m  [1mUSE [MS_GMED_TRANSACTION_NEW][0m
D, [2014-08-01T16:17:54.320753 #4072] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35mActivityDim Load (3.9ms)[0m  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = dbo.ActivityDim'
E, [2014-08-01T16:17:54.347119 #4072] ERROR -- : TinyTds::Error: The multi-part identifier "dbo.ActivityDim" could not be bound.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = dbo.ActivityDim'
```

Comment: That's weird, it should work, what about `Model.attribute_names` ??

Comment: I've attempted reverting from Ruby 2 to Ruby 193 and also reverted to the sqlserver adapter 3.2.13.  No change.  This does not feel like an active_record issue, any longer.  Also, if I execute .connection.tables against the db, I get a complete list of tables.  It simply is not returning the column information.

Comment: One last update.  I can direct that exact same script at a different server (SqlServer 10.50.4) and it works fine.  There is something with the original server (10.50.25) that simply is not communicating the information.  Not sure why, but that's just the way it is until I figure it out.

Comment: Can you successfully query e.g. `Model.all`?

Comment: Following up on this some more.  Column_names returns an empty array [].  An array of #<Model > is returned, one for each column, when I execute pp ActivityDim.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '#{Model.table_name}'").  A coworker thinks this might be security related on the sqlserver side, but can't imagine what.  And if it is security, it returns table names just fine.  This is weird.